# How do I change a ListView dynamically on DataBound?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ListView with a template, it puts a bunch of data in, like X Y Z.

I want to hide show some columns based on criteria, so I have ItemDataBound event, but I don't know how to get the actual listview row so I can do things to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the ListViewItemEventArgs' Item property to get at the current item (the one being bound to data).

The sample code below (which shows how to customize a ListView item in the ItemDataBound event) was taken from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx):

```
protected void ContactsListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    Label EmailAddressLabel;
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        // Display the e-mail address in italics.
        EmailAddressLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("EmailAddressLabel");
        EmailAddressLabel.Font.Italic = true;

        System.Data.DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
        string currentEmailAddress = rowView["EmailAddress"].ToString();
        if (currentEmailAddress == "orlando0@adventure-works.com")
        {
            EmailAddressLabel.Font.Bold = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that FindControl method is what I needed, worked a treat!